# Find the column name of the max value of a row in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using a pandas data frame in Python and have 121 columns and 5 rows. I want to find the max value in each row and print the name of the column where it occurs. I really have no idea how I would even begin to do this but I would appreciate the help.

Edit: the column names are strings

Edit: Some example scenario is:
[image]

and for this example I would want something like:

```
id: 000621fb3cbb32d8935728e48679680e
breed: african_hunting_dog
confidence: 0.011319
```

etc for all 3 rows

Answer (score 3):

You can using `idxmax` and `max` with `axis=1`

```
df.idxmax(axis=1)
df.max(axis=1)
```

Comment: That does get the max value of each row, but doesn't get the column name where that value occurs

Comment: @tethys4 did you try `df.idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: That one gives me an error. "TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype"

Comment: @tethys4 so you have string type columns ?

Comment: Yes, I should've said that in the beginning

Comment: @tethys4 I mean your columns type are string ?

Comment: Yes. They're names of animals.

Comment: I just want to get the name of the column where the highest value occurred. So say in row 1 I have values 0, 5, 2,4 in c1, c2, c3,c4. Then I want to print c2, 5 or something like that. I don't want to compare the column names, only get the name where the max occurred in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for beginner:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','B','C','D','E'], 'Col2': [4,2,6,3,2], 'Col3':[3,6,4,3,1]})
for x in range(len(df)):
    dt = df.iloc[x]
    if dt[1] > dt[2]:
        print ('Col2:{}'.format(dt[1]))
    elif dt[1] < dt[2]:
        print ('Col3:{}'.format(dt[2]))
    else:
        print ('Both cols are same')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for col in df.columns:
       if df[col].values[-1] == df.iloc[-1].max():
          print(col)
```

or alternatively

```
    [x if df[x].values[-1] == df.iloc[-1].max() for x in df.columns]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.